# Pass function as parameter to parent method from derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following code, where the `execute()` method accepts a function as a parameter and executes it. The `start()` method then calls `execute()` in order to run `method1()`.

```
class Test
{
  int Test::start(void)
  {
    execute(&Test::method1);
    return 1;
  }

  void Test::execute(void(Test::*func)(void))
  {
    (this->*func)();
  }

  void Test::method1(void)
  {
    //Do something...
  }
}
```

Now I want to modify this so I achieve the following:

- Create a base class called `TestRunner` and and move the `execute()` method to it
- Have `Test` inherit from `TestRunner`, where it can call the `execute()` method to run its local methods

I am trying the following, but got stuck in how I should specify the method parameter in `execute()` i.e. what right now I have as `TestRunner::*func`.

```
class TestRunner
{
  public:
    TestRunner()
    {
       //Do something...
    }
  protected:
    void execute(void(TestRunner::*func)(void))
    {
      (this->*func)();
    }
}

class Test : TestRunner
{
    public:
      Test() : TestRunner()
      {

      }

      int start()
      {
        TestRunner::execute(&Test::method1);
        return 1;
      }

    private:
      void method1(void)
      {
        //Do something
      }    
}
```

If I compile the code like it is I obviously get these errors:

> no matching function for call to 'Test::execute(void (Test::*)())'

and

> no known conversion for argument 1 from 'void (Test::*)()' to 'void
>   (TestRunner::*)()'

Can anyone guide me in the right direction here or do I need to do something completely different to achieve what I want?

Comment: Whats wrong with virtual methods?

Comment: Seem like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @MohamadElghawi Care to elaborate?

Comment: @RSahu I thought I was pretty clear in what I'm trying to achieve and my attempted solution...I need a class to inherit from another class, and from the derived class be able to call a method in the parent class and pass it another class as a parameter.

Comment: @SeverusSnape, I understand that that's your implementation strategy. I don't think that's the real problem. Anyway, the only way you can do that is through the use of [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) or a `virtual` member function in the base class.

Comment: Instead of `TestRunner::execute(&Test::method1);` use `TestRunner::execute(static_cast<void(Test::*)(void)>(&Test::method1));`. The `static_cast<>` will tell the compiler that you know what you're doing. Remeber to make your methods virtual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this answer here to come up with a solution: [C++ Pointers to Member Functions Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645046/c-pointers-to-member-functions-inheritance/645170#645170)

Create a callback class:

```
class Callback
{
    public:
        virtual ~Callback() { }
        virtual void doSomething()=0;
};
```

Extend the callback class to define how a function is executed and use a template:

```
template<class T>
class BCallback: Callback
{
    public:
        ~BCallback() { }
        BCallback(T *obj, void(T::*fn)()): obj_(obj), fn_(fn) { };

        void doSomething()
        {
            (obj_->*fn_)();
        }

    private:
        T *obj_;
        void(T::*fn_)();
};
```

Use a callback object in the base class:

```
class TestRunner
{
    protected:
        void execute(Callback *cb)
        {
            cb->doSomething();
        }
};
```

Run the method from the derived class:

```
class Test: TestRunner
{
    public:
        int start()
        {
            BCallback<Test> cb(this, &Test::method1);
            this->execute(&cb);
            return 1;
        }

    private:
        void method1(void)
        {
            //Do something
        }   
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `typedef` like this:

```
typedef void(Test::*Callback)(void);
```

You can then make your executing function take objects of type `Callback`. It will look like this `Test::execute(Callback)`.

When calling it, use `static_cast<>`:

```
Test tester;
tester.execute(static_cast<Callback>(&DerivedTest::someMethod));
```

Example `Test::execute(Callback)` implementation:

```
Test::execute(Callback cb) {
    (this->*cb)();
}
```

This way you can avoid writing whole two new classes (one of them a template, even!) just to do a simple thing. As a bonus, you can use function overloading to get `Test::execute` for different function signatures.